# How to find value within a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have an API response returning the following json:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusText": "Ok",
    "data": {
        "testId": "2278816_AklcAQ_E6B",
        "jsonUrl": "https://www.webpagetest.org/jsonResult.php?test=2278816_AklcAQ_E6B",
        "xmlUrl": "https://www.webpagetest.org/xmlResult/2278816_AklcAQ_E6B/",
        "userUrl": "https://www.webpagetest.org/result/2278816_AklcAQ_E6B/",
        "summaryCSV": "https://www.webpagetest.org/result/2278816_AklcAQ_E6B/page_data.csv",
        "detailCSV": "https://www.webpagetest.org/result/2278816_AklcAQ_E6B/requests.csv",
    },
}
```

I then parse this into a dictionary:

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

- now from here what I need to do is find the value of key 'testId', and store that in a variable.

But I've tried a load of things and I can't get it working, I think the nested nature of this is making it harder (total newbie here)

Thanks

Comment: I think I've answered it.  `print(json_data['data']['testId'])`

Comment: @jromero all this is to say, you should probably draw up an answer to your question based on your findings, and then you can accept your own answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (assuming you have the json you have written in the file temp.json) or coming from a request for that matter:

```
import json

# Write code to read a json file and convert to Python dictionary
with open('temp.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

print(json_data["data"]["testId"])
```